# Q: ANTLR 4 Grammar recognition of whole odd value not only the last digit

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to make grammar for the calculator, however it have to be working only for odd numbers.

For example it works like that:
If I put `123` the result is `123`.
If I put `1234` the result is `123`, and the token recognition error at: `4` but should be at: `1234`.

There is my grammar:

```
grammar G;
DIGIT:    ('0'..'9') * ('1' | '3' | '5' | '7'| '9');
operator : ('+' | '-' | '*' | ':');
result: DIGIT operator (DIGIT | result);
```

I mean specifically to make that, the `1234` should be recognized as an error, not only the last digit.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, clarify your question.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the definition of `DIGIT`?

Comment: I'm trying to get an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

The way that tokenization works is that it tries to find the longest prefix of the input that matches any of your regular expressions and then produces the appropriate token, consuming that prefix. So when the input is `1234`, it sees `123` as the longest prefix that matches the `DIGIT` pattern (which should really be called `ODD_INT` or something) and produces the corresponding token. Then it sees the remaining 4 and produces an error because no rule matches it.

Note that it's not necessarily only the last digit that produces the error. For the input `1324`, it would produce a `DIGIT` token for `13` and then a token recognition error for `24`.

So how can you get the behaviour that you want? One approach would be to rewrite your pattern to match all sequences of digits and then use a semantic predicate to verify that the number is odd. The way that semantic predicates work on lexer rules is that it first takes the longest prefix that matches the pattern (without taking into account the predicate) and then checks the predicate. If the predicate is false, it moves on to the other patterns - it does not try to match the same pattern to a smaller input to make the predicate return true. So for the input `1234`, the pattern would match the entire number and then the predicate would return false. Then it would try the other patterns, none of which match, so you'd get a token recognition error for the full number.

```
ODD_INT: ('0'..'9') + { Integer.parseInt(getText()) % 2 == 1 }?;
```

The down side of this approach is that you'll need to write some language-specific code (and if you're not using Java, you'll need to adjust the above code accordingly).

Alternatively, you could just recognize all integers in the lexer - not just odd ones - and then check whether they're odd later during semantic analysis.

If you do want to check the oddness using patterns only, you can also work around the problem by defining rules for both odd and even integers:

```
ODD_INT: ('0'..'9') * ('1' | '3' | '5' | '7'| '9');
EVEN_INT: ('0'..'9') * ('0' | '2' | '4' | '6'| '8');
```

This way for an input like `1234`, the longest match would always be `1234`, not `123`. It's just that this would match the `EVEN_INT` pattern, not `ODD_INT`. So you wouldn't get a token recognition error, but, if you consistently only use `ODD_INT` in the grammar, you would get an error saying that an `ODD_INT` was expected, but an `EVEN_INT` found.

Comment: You're great! Thank you. Now I understand where the problem was.